# Does Mathematica support collaborative filtering and recommendation systems?

Tags: packages, curated-data, data-mining

Does *Mathematica* support collaborative filtering and recommendation systems such as can be found in Apache Mahout?

I could not find any resources about advanced data mining techniques, beyond clustering and NN algorithms. Does anyone know any *Mathematica* libraries that support advanced data mining?

The problem:

I'm building a specific type of a recommendation engine.

Data:

- each product can belong to many categories
- categories form a forest
- products are organized in a graph to show the relationship that consuming an entry level product X will make the more advanced product Y more suitable for the consumer
- for each consumer we have a timeseries of choosen products and the objective and subjective satisfaction levels

Desired outputs:

1. ranked list of products per category that would maximize the objective satisfaction level while still in a threshold of the subjective satisfaction
2. Rank products according to subjective satisfaction but occuring in preferable circumstances (if you've found the right patterns of when to introduce a product use product rating when introduced in a similar pattern)

Comment: As it is, this is a very vague question. Maybe you should be more specific about what you are looking for or what Problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could state more clearly what you mean by "advanced data mining". Searching for `"mathematica data mining"` returns [this commercial package](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/products/mlf/) and [this free link to WEKA](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/products/weka/) by the same company within the first few results, so I am very surprised at your claim that you could not find any resources at all. Are you specifically looking for the functionality described in your question title, or something else?

Comment: @OleksandrR. you can recommend both mathematica packages and general techniques that could help to solve the problem presented in the question. I'd rather stick non-commercial solutions.